# How do I know which method will be called in Python 3?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have these classes in my exercises:

```
class A:
    def accept(self,v):
        v.visitA(self)
class B(A):
    def accept(self,v):
        v.visitB(self)
class C:
    def accept(self,v):
        v.visitC(self)
class Visitor:
    def visitA(self,x):
        return x.accept(self)
    def visitB(self,x):
        pass
    def visitC(self,x):
        pass
```

And my question is that `x.accept(self)` in method visitA of class Visitor can call (indirectly) which method of class Visitor?
I am not really understand these code despite reading about python inheritance. Is there anybody can help me to explain this code?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That code looks broken. Try to have a visitor accept an A instance, and it'll go into infinite recursion and crash with a stack overflow.

Comment: You can see that here: http://ideone.com/RMaK02

Comment: Maybe my teacher intentionally wrote like that. I think he just want to focus on the question that which method will be called in that progress